# How to pass values into _targets.R or use dynamic variables

Tags: r, shiny, targets-r-package

I have a shiny app that sources and calls `tar_make()` a `_targets.R` file. In this file I have two variables who's values I have hard coded but I want to set these variable values dynamically from input texts my Shiny UI. Is there a way for me to pass these variables to the _targets.R file? Or is there some method provided by targets that can help me?

This is the first part of my _targets.R file, `level.name` and `level.value` are the variables that I want to set dynamically.

[image]

Also, is it possible to run the tar_make() function multiple times, each time passing in different values for `level.name` and `level.value` ?

**Edit: creating a write_pipline**

**app.R**

```
source("pipeline.R")

level.name <- "Order"
level.value <- "ORDER Poputre"

level_name_dir <- file.path("level", level.name)

level_value_dir <- file.path(level_name_dir, level.value)
if (!dir.exists(level_value_dir)) dir.create(level_value_dir, recursive = TRUE)

## note: level_value_dir <- level/Order/ORDER Poputre

write_pipeline(level_value_dir, level.name, level.value)
script <- file.path(level_value_dir, "_targets.R")
store <- file.path(level_value_dir)


tar_make(
    script = script,
    store = store
)

ui <- htmlTemplate(...)
server <- function(input, output) ...
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**pipeline.R (in the same directory level as app.R)**

```
write_pipeline <- function(
  path,
  level.name,
  level.value
  ) {

  tar_helper(file.path(path, "_targets.R"), {
    library(targets)
    tar_option_set(packages = c("data.table", "tidyverse", "rjson"))
    files.sources <- list.files("_functions")
    sapply(paste("_functions/", files.sources, sep = ""), source)

    list(
      ###########################
      ### Set level variables ###
      ###########################
      tar_target(
        level_name,
        level.name
      ),
      tar_target(
        level_value,
        level.value
      )
     })
    }
```

This seems to create the **_targets.R** file and its required directories in the intended place. But the variables that I pass to write_pipeline are not being recognized when I call **tar_make**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You could programmatically write `_targets.R` before running the pipeline. This is what https://github.com/wlandau/targets-shiny/blob/main/R/pipeline.R does. Alternatively, you could `level.name` and `level.value` from file targets and write the files in the app's file space.

Comment: @landau thank you! This is helpful I will try implement this. I am struggling to find good documentation about what tar_helpers does, specifically what the path parameter does

Comment: It's documented at http://docs.ropensci.org/targets/reference/tar_helper.html. It writes R code to a file you specify at `path`.

Comment: @landau thanks for your advice, I am implementing write_pipeline in my code. When I call write_pipeline, I pass my variables to it and can print them out in the tar_helper function, but when I call tar_make() they seem to be gone and I am getting an error as the variable name does not have a variable

Comment: Hard to say without a reprex, but the general technique worked in https://github.com/wlandau/targets-shiny. The `_targets.R` file needs to load the helper script you write, and the helper script or the `_targets.R` file needs to assign the global variables you need.

Comment: Thanks for your advice once again. I think I understand what you mean but have included the code above, thanks for your time

Comment: I suspect the issue might be "The _targets.R file needs to load the helper script you write".  I am not sure how to achieve this, hopefully the code that I added above will help

Comment: Looks like values for variables `level.name` and `level.value` were not inserted into the code. You can verify this by reading the `_targets.R` file that was generated. With `tar_helper()`, you can use [`!!` from tidy evaluation](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/) to insert values from the environment, e.g. `!!level.name`.

Comment: Thats it! It now works as expected, thank you very much for your time and expertise! It has been very helpful to me